# Is it possible to write a type trait that checks if a type is a specific type with an addition?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, c++20, type-traits

I have a type:

```
struct A {}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_A_v = false;

template<>
constexpr bool is_A_v<A> = true; // here I don't know how to apply std::remove_cvref_t<?> before checking?
```

I am new to type traits so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're using C++20, why not use a concept?

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to do? Is the goal of `is_A_v<T>` to check that `std::remove_cvref_t<T>` is `A`?

Comment: Yea, I want to check if something is a type by first cleaning the type, so that references and other things are treated all as A. A, A&, A&&, const A& should all return true.

Comment: Do you need to use specialization to implement this?  (It does have the advantage of being extensible after the fact.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment, you're look for:

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_A = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, A>;
```

In C++20, you could spell this as a concept:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept is_A = std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, A>;
```

Which has some slight syntactic advantages, but also prevents people from specializing the trait after the fact.

Comment: Why is the inline there? Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes. constexpr variables are not inline implicitly, only constexpr static member variables are inline implicitly.